# Contour Integration of 1/sin^(2)z dz

Tags: calculus, integration, contour-integration

For $R > 0$, assume ΓR is a circle $\{z \in \mathbb C : |z| = R\}$ with anticlockwise direction. 
For which $R>0$, is $f(z) = \int\limits_{ΓR} \frac{1}{\sin^2(z)} dz$ continous on ΓR and evaluate the integral over this ΓR.

As sin is continuous everywhere I found that I am just required to find the contour integral over 0 to infinity ie

$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sin^2(z)} dz$.

I am given the information that $\sin(z) =  \frac{e^{iz} - e^{iz}}{2i}$
but confused on how to find it for $\sin^2 (x)$ as asked in the question.

Comment: Note that $\sin^2(z)=\frac12(1-\cos(2z))$.

Comment: As written, it seems that you stated the question incorrectly. 1) $R$ is not used in the integral; probably you wanted to integrate $\int\limits_{\Gamma R}$? 2) "For which $R>0$" what? Do you want the value of the integral? Or, probably, "for which $R>0$ does the integral converge"?

Comment: You're right! I've edited the question, hope it is a bit more clear now.